# ParseException about EOF in Hive

Tags: java, hive

I can execute the SQL in the shell:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/sql.txt' INTO TABLE files;
```

Here's the content in the sql.txt:

```
4e6c924a-1fa2-4326-86eb-975d1007f0a6 FileScoreConverterTest.java /home/xiehaozhe/Development/Kloud-Document-Analyzer/kda/src/test/java/com/kda/filescore/type/FileScoreConverterTest.java
ab6ee610-c980-4ff7-b472-8546766e0f89 FileWordCountConverterTest.java /home/xiehaozhe/Development/Kloud-Document-Analyzer/kda/src/test/java/com/kda/filescore/type/FileWordCountConverterTest.java
```

The struct of the table(named *files*) is

```
guid STRING
filename STRING
filepath STRING
```

If I execute the sql in Java, I got an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 40000, cause: FAILED: ParseException line 1:54 mismatched input ';' expecting EOF near 'files'
```

Here's the code:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
String sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '" + sqlFilePath + "' INTO TABLE files;";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseAddress, databaseUsername, databasePassword);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write a query in the shell, you should use ';' at the end of the SQL statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/sql.txt' INTO TABLE files;
```

However, you CANNOT use ';' at the end of the SQL statement when you're using Java:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/sql.txt' INTO TABLE files
```

So, that's the reason cause the exception.